# Coq Dependent pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, coq, dependent-type

Currently I'm reading [Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) and its [exercise](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/).

In the `HW12.v` in the exercies, Heterogeneous Lists is defined as

```
Section hlist.
Variable A : Type.
Variable B : A -> Type.

Inductive hlist : list A -> Type :=
| HNil : hlist nil
| HCons : forall (x : A) (ls : list A), B x -> hlist ls -> hlist (x :: ls).

Variable elm : A.

Inductive member : list A -> Type :=
| HFirst : forall ls, member (elm :: ls)
| HNext : forall x ls, member ls -> member (x :: ls).

Fixpoint hget ls (mls : hlist ls) : member ls -> B elm :=
  match mls with
    | HNil => fun mem =>
      match mem in member ls' return (match ls' with
                                        | nil => B elm
                                        | _ :: _ => unit
                                      end) with
        | HFirst _ => tt
        | HNext  _ => tt
      end
    | HCons x mls' => fun mem =>
      match mem in member ls' return (match ls' with
                                        | nil => Empty_set
                                        | x' :: ls'' =>
                                          B x' -> (member ls'' -> B elm)
                                          -> B elm
                                      end) with
        | HFirst _ => fun x _ => x
        | HNext mem' => fun _ get_mls' => get_mls' mem'
      end x (hget mls')
  end.
End hlist.
```

.

In order to guess why *convoy pattern* is used in `HCons` pattern, I tried to rewrite it as

```
    | HCons x mls' => fun mem =>
      match mem in member ls' return (match ls' with
                                        | nil => Empty_set
                                        | _ :: _ => B elm
                                      end) with
        | HFirst _ => x
        | HNext _ mem' => (hget mls') mem'
      end
```

.

Then Coq didn't accept the change, but the error occurred in `HNil` pattern as follows.

```
Error:
In environment
A : Type
B : A -> Type
elm : A
hget : forall ls : list A, hlist ls -> member ls -> B elm
ls : list A
mls : hlist ls
mem : member ?l@{l0:=nil}
The term
 "match mem in (member ls') return match ls' with
                                   | nil => B elm
                                   | _ :: _ => unit
                                   end with
  | HFirst _ => tt
  | HNext _ _ => tt
  end" has type "match ?l@{l0:=nil} with
                 | nil => B elm
                 | _ :: _ => unit
                 end" while it is expected to have type "B elm".
```

It is reasonable if errors happen in `HCons` pattern, but why in `HNil`, which was once reasoned correctly?

Comment: Your code is working on version 8.6; I just added `Set Implicit Arguments. Unset Strict Implicit.` and put an extra argument in the pattern of the `HNext` branches.

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim I used version 8.5pl2 above, and it works on 8.6! Thank you! But still confusing the older version's behavior.

Comment: When you say it works, does Coq accept the definition or does it trigger the error in the second branch ? (because I tried version 8.6 and the second behaviour happens). Note that (in 8.6), when using `refine` in proof mode using the original version of the function, we get an error similar to the reported error. When we add a `return` clause to the outer `match`, the error is again located in the second branch.

Comment: @eponier I meant that Coq accepts the definition in 8.6. I downloaded my version with OPAM. Here's the exact code that I entered: https://gist.github.com/arthuraa/be64b957d75f07e92c26d8897781a7d0.

Comment: Thank you, but what works is the original definition, not the other simpler one.